# Getting a datetime to php from javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm working with a JQuery datetime picker and am trying to save the selected date time into the php variable in order to save it into mysql database. I've seen alot of different eaxmples on here and have tried a few but none seem to be working  for me. The output of the date time seems to be outputed to an array, this is where i am having difficulty before conversion.

this is my JQuery picker and posting method:

```
$(function () {

    $('*[name=date2]').appendDtpicker({
        "inline": true,
            "allowWdays": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
            // 0: Sun, 1: Mon, 2: Tue, 3: Wed, 4: Thr, 5: Fri, 6: Sat
        "futureOnly": true,
            "autodateOnStart": false
    });

    $('#btn_input').on('click', function () {
        var input = $('*[name=date2]').handleDtpicker('getDate');

        console.log(input);

        $.post("backend.php", {
            'input': input
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert("Server Response: " + data);
        });
    });
});
```

This is the backend.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

print_r($_POST);
?>
```

and finally this is the output in the alert:

```
Server Response: 
Array
(
[input] => Tue Mar 31 2015 11:20:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)
)
```

and the output if backend.php is run:

```
Array ( )
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction i appreciate all the help, new to php and very confused!

Comment: If you access backend.php directly it's not going to have any value - it's only set if you actually run the javascript which is POSTing the data to the PHP. It looks like your code is already working - `$_POST['input']` contains a date according to your alert.

Comment: What I want to do next is pull the date from the array so it reads: yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss and make this a php datetime variable so i am able to input to my database. Should I have extracted the values before posting?

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery script you have set it to post as name: input, so it will come as `$_POST['input']`

Add this to your backend.php, and you will get the time as unix epoch:

```
if(isset($_POST['input']))
{
    $time = strtotime(preg_replace('/\(.*\)/i', '', $_POST['input']));
    // $time contains unix epoch
    echo date("Y-m-d", $time);  
}
```

Comment: Ok this has definatly fixed the date format issue although the $time variable doesn't seem to be recognized?

    Server Response:
    2015-04-15

And im getting an error on the backend.php page:

    ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: input in C:\wamp\www\gp\backend.php on line 3

 and then the ouput: 

1970-01-01

Comment: Updated with if(isset($_POST['input'])). This will remove the Notice